# Cases with condition and two different outcomes

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Given

```
 t1 = {{{{3}, {2, 5}}, 1}, {{{3}, {2, 7}}, 5}, {{{2, 7}, {3, 7}}, 7}, {{{2, 7}, {3, 5}}, 1}}
```

I want to double the first  part if only one number is present and then switch the first two parts of the sublists. I can do it by splitting:

```
t2 = Cases[t1, {{{a_}, {c_, d_}}, e_} -> {{c, d}, {a, a}, e}]
t3 = Cases[t1, {{{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}}, e_} -> {{c, d}, {a, b}, e}]
Join[t2, t3]
```

resulting in:

```
{{{2, 5}, {3, 3}, 1}, {{2, 7}, {3, 3}, 5}, {{3, 7}, {2, 7}, 7}, {{3, 5}, {2, 7}, 1}}
```

How can I do it in one go using conditions in Cases?

Comment: `Replace[t1,
 {
  {{{a_}, {c_, d_}}, e_} :> {{c, d}, {a, a}, e},
  {{{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}}, e_} :> {{c, d}, {a, b}, e}
  }
 , 1
 ]`

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`PadRight`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadRight.html).

With `t1` in OP

```
Cases[t1, {{a_, b_}, c_} :> {b, PadRight[a, 2, First@a], c}]
```

> ```
> {{{2, 5}, {3, 3}, 1}, {{2, 7}, {3, 3}, 5}, {{3, 7}, {2, 7}, 7}, {{3, 5}, {2, 7}, 1}}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good idea! Great! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
list =
  {{{{3}, {2, 5}}, 1},
   {{{3}, {2, 7}}, 5},
   {{{2, 7}, {3, 7}}, 7},
   {{{2, 7}, {3, 5}}, 1}};

ReplaceAll[{a_} :> {a, a}] @ MapAt[Splice @* Reverse, {All, 1}] @ list
```

returns

```
{{{2, 5}, {3, 3}, 1}, 
 {{2, 7}, {3, 3}, 5}, 
 {{3, 7}, {2, 7}, 7}, 
 {{3, 5}, {2, 7}, 1}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
t1 = {{{{3}, {2, 5}}, 1}, {{{3}, {2, 7}}, 5}, {{{2, 7}, {3, 7}}, 
    7}, {{{2, 7}, {3, 5}}, 1}};
```

**Using `SequenceReplace` (or `SequenceCases`):**

```
SequenceReplace[t1, {{{{a_, b___}, {c_, d_}}, e_}} :> {{c, d}, {a, 
    If[b === {}, a, b]}, e}]
```

**Using `Cases`:**

```
Cases[t1, {{{a_, b___}, {c_, d_}}, 
   e_} :> {{c, d}, {a, If[b === {}, a, b]}, e}]
```

---

*Result:*

> {{{2, 5}, {3, 3}, 1}, {{2, 7}, {3, 3}, 5}, {{3, 7}, {2, 7},    7},
> {{3, 5}, {2, 7}, 1}}

Answer (score 1):

```
t1 = {{{{3}, {2, 5}}, 1}, {{{3}, {2, 7}}, 5},
     {{{2, 7}, {3, 7}}, 7}, {{{2, 7}, {3, 5}}, 1}};
```

---

Using `Replace` from level `1` through depth of `t1` with the following rules:

```
rules = {
        {{a_}, {b__}} :> Splice@{{b}, {a, a}},
        {{c__}, {d__}} :> Splice@{{d}, {c}}
        };

Replace[#, rules, {1, Depth@#}] &@t1
```

*Result*:

> {{{2, 5}, {3, 3}, 1}, {{2, 7}, {3, 3}, 5}, {{3, 7}, {2, 7}, 7}, {{3, 5}, {2, 7}, 1}}